# Submit a list of objects from JS to MVC

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to submit a list of users.
I have a MVC controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Handler(List<User> users) {
   ...
}
```

where User is

```
public class User {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

in JavaScript I send the array by jquery

```
    var users = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        users [i] = {
            name: "User " + i, 
            email: "user" + i + "@test.net"
        }
    }

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
                users: users
        },
        url: "http://test.net/order/handler",
        success: callback
    });
```

I get the list with 3 items, but parameters name and email are NULL.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: How are you trying to access the data in the resulting `users` variable?

Comment: Your class name is 'User', but the type in your list is List<Users> (ie. with an s).

Comment: use json.stringify(users)..

Comment: @Exception: Eh, no. You don't need to (or rather, shouldn't) do that when using jQuery's ajax.

Comment: To Routeburn: I just mistyped. Fixed.

Comment: try ...  data: {
                users:  json.stringify(users)
        }

Comment: It must be accessible as a List.

Comment: To Exception: Tried. Then I get no one item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `[FromBody]` to the parameter? Example:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Handler([FromBody] List<User> users) {
   ...
}
```

Also it's important to set the ContentType of your ajax POST so that the ModelBinder knows what to use:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
            users: users
    },
    url: "http://test.net/order/handler",
    success: callback,
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

Another thing: You may be doing a [Cross-domain ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain) which has several implications. You can consider using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see what is really happening to your request and post an update so we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it because you should be creating an **array** and then add **objects** to it:

```
    var users = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var user = {
            name: "User " + i, 
            email: "user" + i + "@test.net"
        }

        users[i] = user;
    }

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
                users: users
        },
        url: "http://test.net/order/handler",
        success: callback
    });
```

Comment: No, it gives the same result. :-/

Comment: He is doing an array, in his example, he reduces 2 lines doing exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set valid json data:

```
var users = Array(), i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    users[i] =
    {
        name: "User " + i,
        email: "user" + i + "@test.net"
    };
}
```

Then send ajax request with dataType json:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            users: users
        },
        url: "http://test.net/order/handler",
        success: callback
    });
});
```